# Any problem in P can be reduced to the language of odd integers

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np, polynomial-time-reductions

Given $A=\left\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$n$ is odd}\right\}$,  we want to prove that if $S \in P$ then there is a Karp reduction from $S$ to $A$.

My attempt:
If $S \in P$ we can solve $S$ with a reduction that converts in polynomial time an input from $S$ to $A$, but I don't know how to prove formally the function and to show that the function is a reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be any language in $\mathsf{P}$. You are looking for a function $f$ with the following properties:

- $f$ can be computed in polynomial time.
- If $x \in S$ then $f(x) \in A$.
- If $x \notin S$ then $f(x) \notin A$.

Since $S$ is in $\mathsf{P}$, we can determine whether $x \in S$ in polynomial time. Therefore, the reduction $f$ can work as follows:

1. Determine whether $x \in S$.
2. If $x \in S$ then output something in $A$.
3. If $x \notin S$ then output something not in $A$.

You take it from here.

Comment: Thanks! The other side is also a proof?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “the other side”.

Comment: If there is a Karp reduction from $S$ to $A$ then $S \in P$

Comment: You can prove this directly, since $A$ is in P.

Comment: But if I know only that there is a Karp reduction from $S$ to $A$ and I want to prove that $A \in P$ , I need to show that $S$ can be computed in polynomial time?

Comment: That won’t help. You won’t be able to prove that $A$ is in P.

Comment: Thanks! So how I can prove it that $A \in P$ if I know that there is a Karp reduction from $S$ to $A$

Comment: You cannot prove it since it’s not true.

Comment: How you disprove it?

Comment: By means of a counterexample.